# Using multiple alternatives of hashCode() and equals() for sets

Tags: java, set, equals, hashcode

Suppose I have a simple POJO class Class1 , and it has 2 fields of type int.

I've implemented the [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)() and [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)() methods of it to handle exactly those 2 fields, in order to put instances of the class into a set.

So far so good.

Now, I want to have a different set, which considers instances of Class1 to be equal if the first field is equal , making the equality condition weaker. I might even want to have another set which considers only the second field as the one that checks for equality.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Use a Comparator along with TreeMap. The other option is to extend HashMap so it uses a Hash generator instead of hashCode()

Comment: Is it possible to extend the HashSet somehow?

Answer (score 5):

You *can* get that effect by using a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) when providing a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that only inspects the fields you're interested in.

Note, however, that strictly speaking such a `TreeSet` no longer is a "correct" `Set` because it effectively ignores the `equal()` method of your objects:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of *consistent with equals*.) This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 3):

The standard Java libraries don't support this.

And (surprisingly) there doesn't appear to be a `Map` or `Set` class in the Apache Commons Collections or Guava libraries that supports this.

There are probably other libraries that to support this if you look hard enough.

Alternatively, you could write your own ... starting with the standard `HashMap` code.

---

A cheap-and-cheerful alternative is to create a light-weight wrapper class for your element type that delegates most methods to the wrapped class and provides a different `equals` / `hashcode` pair to the original.  There is a small runtime penalty in doing this ... but it is worth considering.

Joachim's suggestion is good too, unless your sets are likely to be particularly big.  (`TreeSet` has `O(logN)` lookup compared with `O(1)` for a properly implemented hash table.)